# c++ error C2512

Tags: c++, constructor

I got the error:

```
error C2512:'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' : no appropriate default
constructor available
```

with the following code:

```
class Sentence
{
public:
    Sentence(void){}
    ~Sentence(void);
    static void CreateHeader(std:string& s);
    class Word {
        public:
            std:ostream s;

            Sentence::Word(){ s<<""; }

            Word(char*);
            ~Word();
    };
};
```

The constructor `Sentence::World(){ s <<""; };` doesnt work.

Comment: Would you translate it to English language?

Comment: What is `std: stream s` supposed to mean?

Comment: Are you intending to derive from std::ostream?

Answer (score 1):

std:ostream has no default contructor - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream

What are you trying to do? Are you looking for std::cout, std::ofstream or maybe std::stringstream ?

Comment: I wanted to have a 'ostream' in my class, and add it some string with an 'operator<<'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the msdn explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9zkz8dx6(v=vs.80).aspx

in brief you need to add a default constructor :

```
Sentence(){}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, but it's the 4th line of my programm, see below

Comment: rather than saying thanks Plus One my post :D

Comment: No, because i had already did that, re read my code in my first post

Comment: Sentence(void){} in the 4th line